# why am I Getting a not allowed error with nginx?

Tags: php, nginx

I have a 405 not allowed when i request any .html or .php with POST method.
im using a windows 10 machine and wsl2 with ubuntu terminal.
this never happened when i used my dual booted ubuntu.
why is this happening.

Answer (score 1):

By default NGINX does not allow POST requests to static files (such as .html). There is a well-known hack to overcome this:

```
  error_page 405 =200 $uri;
```

It works by replacing 405 return code with 200 and serving the request instead of error page. Place it in a location when you want to allow POST requests to static files.

As for `php` you probably haven't configured an interpreter for scripts. Without proper configuration NGINX will show `php` files as plain text files.  [Here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) is an example how nginx can be configured for `php-fpm`.